# how to pass multiple parameters in DELETE method in laravel 5?

Tags: php, html, laravel-5

I am doing project using `laravel 5` framework. I want to pass two `parameter` through `DELETE` method , for my `Controller` class.

**`ex.blade.php`**

```
<td align='center'>
    {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route'=>['commitee-page-member.destroy',$member->id ,$commitee->id]]) !!}                                               
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> </button> 
    {!! Form::close() !!}
</td>
```

when i click button i can see `variable` through `url`:

**URL:**

```
../masterlaw.com/commitee-page-member/1?5
```

I try to different ways , take these `two parameters` 1 and 5.

**controller class code :**

```
public function destroy(Request $request, $id)
{
    //       
    echo $id;
    echo $request['id'];      
}
```

but still I couldn't `retrieve` data . please ,help me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem here is that `destroy()` method of [resource class](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers) only accepts one parameter, the ID. One possible solution is create a controller class (not a resource) and create a method accepting two arguments:

```
class PageController extends Contoller{

    public function destroy(Request $request, $memberId, $commiteeId){
        // echo memberId;
    }
}
```

Name a route fitting your needs and Form's format:

```
Route::get('delete-page/{memberId}/{commiteeId}', [
    'as' => 'destroy', 
    'uses' => 'PageController@destroy'
]);
```

Now your route is prepared to be used with two parameters:

```
{!! Form::open([
    'method' => 'POST', 
    'route' => ['destroy', $member->id, $commitee->id]]) !!}
```

As an additional note, you can read more about *Nested resources*, it could be useful for you if your project is made under an specific structure.

**Edit.**
If you consider necessary keep code at resource class, you can add your custom method and declare it at `routes.php` file before resource declaration:

```
// using "delete" as a verb
Route::delete('memberPage/customDestroy/{memberId}/{commiteeId}', 'MyResource@customDestroy');
Route::resource('memberPage', 'MyResource');
```

Comment: can i do without create new controller class. i mean , can i add new method same resource class. I call like this . ***    {!! Form::open([ 'method' => 'POST', 'route' => ['commitee-page-member.destroy_members', $member->id, $commitee->id]]) !!}  /// ***//////route ///////////Route::resource('commitee-page-member','CommiteeMemberController');

Comment: I think the problem in the OP is specific to a version prior to 5.4 because I am using Laravel 5.4 and I found that the standard delete routes (generated by a Route::resource) can receive a Request object. I require my user to input a text field to confirm deletion. Sorry I cannot be more specific about which version this was added.

Answer (score 2):

Your code was almost ok, just have to make few edit

`./masterlaw.com/commitee-page-member/1?val=5&&val2=4`

and in the controller

```
public function destroy(Request $request, $id)
{      
 echo $id;
 echo $request->val;
 echo $request->val2;     
}
```

when you are going to add new get parameters inside the resource controller's function

you just have to add Request `$request parameter` in the function and then you can catch all the values. like for edit function

```
manage/pages/1/edit?language=en

public function edit(Request $request,$id){
 $getvalue=$request->language;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you must define all parameters in your method of your controller but you are free to use all of them or not

```
public function destroy(Request $request, $commiteId , $mebmerId)
{
    //your awesome codes     
}
```

and you must pass them with key

note: Form::open is not available in laravel 5+ so you must use the route helper function

```
route("myroute.name",["commiteeId"=>commiteeId,"memberId"=>$memberId])
```